# Google Pay - request failed on Android 11

Tags: android, google-pay

We are using Google Pay in our app with latest play-services-wallet:18.0.0
One of the users reported issues after upgrade to Android 11 on Pixel 2.

Since I don't have this devices, I have tried to recreate this issue on emulator with Google Play.

Calling `AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(request), activity, GOOGLE_PAYMENT_REQUEST_CODE)`
results in following dialog:
[image: dialog]

onActivityResult will then provide intent with Status class with code `409` - aborted

Emulator with Android 10 and Android 9 is working just fine.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Edit:
Logcat from user:

```
09-11 17:06:13.547  8927 16994 E TapAndPay: Unable retrieve off body sensor. Sensor is null. [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
09-11 17:06:13.550  8836  9848 W TapAndPayUtils: Failed to retrieve in app payment credential! status = 13 message = Storage key missing
09-11 17:06:13.528  8927 16994 E TapAndPay: Unable retrieve off body sensor. Sensor is null. [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation: serviceID=79, operation=RetrieveInAppPaymentCredential [CONTEXT service_id=259 ]
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation: OperationException[Status{statusCode=Storage key missing, resolution=null}]
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at atri.b(:com.google.android.gms@203315046@20.33.15 (150400-330018294):24)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at atse.a(:com.google.android.gms@203315046@20.33.15 (150400-330018294):3)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at yof.run(:com.google.android.gms@203315046@20.33.15 (150400-330018294):11)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at blzm.run(:com.google.android.gms@203315046@20.33.15 (150400-330018294):2)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at qzr.b(:com.google.android.gms@203315046@20.33.15 (150400-330018294):12)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at qzr.run(:com.google.android.gms@203315046@20.33.15 (150400-330018294):7)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at rfq.run(:com.google.android.gms@203315046@20.33.15 (150400-330018294):0)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation: Caused by: atpe: No storage key available
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at atpk.a(:com.google.android.gms@203315046@20.33.15 (150400-330018294):9)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at atkt.a(:com.google.android.gms@203315046@20.33.15 (150400-330018294):81)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     at atri.b(:com.google.android.gms@203315046@20.33.15 (150400-330018294):10)
09-11 17:06:13.531  8927 16994 E AsyncOperation:     ... 9 more
```

Comment: Click "Learn more"!

Comment: That just redirects me to https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/support/troubleshooting
That doesnt help at all.

Comment: What about using an image that has `Android 11 (Google APIs)` instead of just Play services / play store?

Comment: Sorry, posted wrong url, the actual url is: https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7644087?p=payment_error&visit_id=637354311341713599-2188268801&rd=1

Comment: @Shark I thought that the one with Google APIs has less ten the one with Play Store. I will give it a try

Comment: Nope, GoogleAPIs actually has more than the playstore one. E.g. places, placepicker, and a bunch of other things not available (but usually expected) in the playstore one.

Comment: Well result is the same. But it seems that it is not the same issue the user reported (he cant see any dialog appeared). I have added part of logcat that seems to have something to do with it